# Printing from a passive handheld printer on Android through Bluetooth programatically

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, rfcomm

I have a hand held Bluetooth printer model # SUP80M1 from SunPhor company from China. 
It is badly documented and the only statement about the Bluetooth interface from the 80 line documentation is below:

"This printer  has a Bluetooth communication interface (slave unit), the name of the default machine is: CCD-308B, the initial password is 0000. After a PDA or other equipment which has been successfully connected to the printing machine, SPP agreement can be used to operate the printing machine."

Android requires UUID to connect to a device. How can I have a UUID from the device name, which is not discoverable.

I am clueless as to how to connect to the device. This device is not discoverable under Bluetooth devices in settings.

The vendor says he does not have any documentation, sample code or anything. Somebody, please throw some light and give some right direction to me. The project is in a critical state and I am not sure about what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a button or SOMETHING that puts the device into a mode where it is discoverable. If there is no button then maybe it happens at power on.

If it wants a PIN code then it must be < BT2.1.

SPP = Serial Port Profile? The shortform 16-bit UUID for that service is 0x1101, but then you have to work out what the protocol over SPP is.

Comment: The printer is Bluetooth version 2.0 where as my Android phone (HTC Incredible S) is of Bluetooth version 2.1. Can I connect the phone to the printer? Or is there any known issue in this scenario?

The printer is still not detectable from my HTC Incredible S, where as it is discoverable from Samsung Galaxy (Donut, BT2.0).

Comment: BT2.1 devices should be backwardly compatible with 2.0 devices. Should ask for PIN code.